# PyQt5 QGraphicScene boundaries

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

When adding lines or a path to my GraphicsScene, the window will eventually grow (not the display size, but scroll bars appear, i hope you get me).
My main concern is that a point with fixed coordinates in my scene will not look fixed, as the screen moves with updating the display.
Is there a way to fix the boundaries so that no more can a certain area can be displayed?
Edit: What i'm going for is no scrollbars, just a fixed (x1, y1, x2, y2) rectangle where the display happens.

Comment: If you could update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I might have a closer look.

Comment: How does the user add the lines?

Comment: I ask it because, for example, if the user adds the lines by drag-and-drop and we say that the line when it is released occupies a space that comes out of space, what should happen in that case? Should only one part be shown?

Answer (score 0):

The general approach might be looking for view and bounds properties and also flags that define the scene's or view's behaviour.
If these do not exist, you could look at disconnecting signals or reimplementing slots to suppress or manipulate the "growing" of your view.

Unfortunately, the documentation for PyQt5 seems to be rather lacking currently:

- https://pyqt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/qtwidgets/qgraphicsscene.html
- https://pyqt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/qtwidgets/qgraphicsview.html

so you'll have to resort to the Qt docs:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html

---

If your question is just about suppressing scroll bars, have a look at

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ScrollBarPolicy-enum

Comment: Thanks, but i think i've worked out what i need. I'm not sure why, but using the method setRect() with a QRectF the size of my scene fixed the coordinates.